# stack commands other than init not ever finishing

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I'm trying to run haskell code using `stack ghci`, but I am having this problem where `stack build`, `stack ghci`, `stack` anything except `init` (which runs fine), hangs pretty indefinitely.

Oh and this is on windows 10, running a stack I just downloaded last week. Here's the verbose output of the command it seems to get stuck on when I run `stack ghci`:

```
2016-06-12 17:22:46.134672: [debug] Run process: 
C:\...\stack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3.exe 
   --builddir=.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3 
   configure 
       --with-ghc=C:\...\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\bin\ghc.exe 
       --with-ghc-pkg=C:\...\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\bin\ghc-pkg.exe 
       --user 
       --package-db=clear 
       --package-db=global 
       --package-db=C:\...\stack\snapshots\ee4b7647\pkgdb 
       --package-db=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\pkgdb 
       --libdir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\lib 
       --bindir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\bin 
       --datadir=C:\...\assignments\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\share 
       --libexecdir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\libexec 
       --sysconfdir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\etc 
       --docdir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\doc\mp1-haskell-0.1.0.0 
       --htmldir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\doc\mp1-haskell-0.1.0.0 
       --haddockdir=C:\...\mp1-haskell\.stack-work\install\5c0a1b09\doc\mp1-haskell-0.1.0.0 
       --dependency=base=base-4.8.2.0-14035a44a8b95c6832da6dae1420f59e 
       --extra-include-dirs=C:\...\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include 
       --extra-lib-dirs=C:\...\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib 
       --enable-tests 
       --enable-benchmarks @(stack_9kewhubnl5WIl89fhd1ea2:System.Process.Read src/System\Process\Read.hs:283:3)
```

Comment: Did `stack build` ever work for you or is this a new problem?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, this is my first time using stack. So no, it has never worked for me.

Comment: if you go in an empty folder (no stack.yaml nor xyz.cabal present) and run `stack ghci` - what does it tell you? (Probably it just takes some time to compile all the dependencies this might have - this can take quite some time - for example if you compile idris you might have time to grab and trink a cup of coffee / tea)

Comment: sorry for the slow response. It actually gets all the way to the prelude. Strange, I feel like that means something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: It actually runs all the way to the prelude, i.e. all the way through. Strange, I'm sure that means something but I'm not sure what. This cabal is being used by at least 20 other people and no one has reported problems but me. Here's the output btw `Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Error parsing targets: The specified targets matched no packages.
Perhaps you need to run 'stack init'?
Warning: build failed, but optimistically launching GHCi anyway
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 7.10.3: 
Prelude>` Obviously cut down for size